# Facebook Graph API Share method break the href link

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook Graph API with Javascript to allow the user to share a link. Simple enough.

**Javascript code:**

```
var _link = 'http://example.com/ca.a/4102/540/en/1/31';

function share() {
    FB.ui({  method: 'share',
             href: _link,
             redirect_uri: _link,
             quote: 'simple name'
          }, 
          function (response) { }
    );
}
```

This operation results it a link generated by Facebook API:

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/share?app_id=596131650587698&channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2F0sTQzbapM8j.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df2c247478a4c94c%26domain%3Dwebcand.com%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwebcand.com%252Ff2f0001bcf7065%26relation%3Dopener&display=popup&e2e=%7B%7D&href=http%3A%2F%2Fwebcand.com%2Fca.a%2F4102%2F540%2Fen%2F1%2F31&locale=en_US&name=simple%20name&next=http%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2F0sTQzbapM8j.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df572851e5571f8%26domain%3Dwebcand.com%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Ff2f0001bcf7065%26relation%3Dopener%26frame%3Df1d6415a361a248%26result%3D%2522xxRESULTTOKENxx%2522&quote=Click%20here%20to%20take%20the%20interview&sdk=joey&version=v2.8
```

Note the `&next=` parameter. Facebook has wrapped the link I provided with additional data, redirecting it to `Fstaticxx.facebook.com`.

So now, the share feed looks like this:

[image]

The "***Object reference not set to an instance of an object***" error message is happening because the link I provided expects the format `http://example.com/ca.a/A/B/C/D/E` and if one of these `/` params is missing, the exception occurs. So obviously the link alteration causes this.

Passing the URL as `A-B-C-D-E` works fine, so my conclusion is that the `/` signs are being **removed**.

Any suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: Why are you supplying a redirect_uri parameter to begin with? In combination with FB.ui that does not make much sense.

Comment: @CBroe the `redirect_uri` is a part of the method parameters which sets to which URL clicking on your post will lead... I'm not catching what you mean...

Comment: No, you got that wrong. The `redirect_uri` is the URL the user that is using the dialog gets redirected to, after they are finished with the dialog. But it only makes sense to specify that when you are actually using the URL redirect version of the dialogs; with FB.ui, that parameter has no meaning whatsoever. The post itself links to whatever URL you shared via the `href` parameter.